# This code doesn't execute properly. Can someone help me out here?

Tags: java

```
/* File name: IsConsonant.java
 * -------------------------------------- 
 * Tests alphabets  for consonants
 */

import acm.program.*;

public class IsConsonant extends ConsoleProgram {

    public void run() {
        String ch = readLine ("Enter an alphabet: ");
        isEnglishConsonant(ch.charAt(0));
        if (true){
           println("True");
        } else { 
           println("False");}
        }

    private boolean isEnglishConsonant(char ch){
        switch (Character.toUpperCase(ch)){
            case 'A': 
            case 'E': 
            case 'I': 
            case 'O': 
            case 'U':
                return false;
        default:
                return true;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: and what is the problem? what should be the result? and what is the result right now?

Comment: Please change the title of the question into something more fitting and less general.

Comment: @Erno: second that. And user233444, if you have found that one of the answers provided helped you, please accept it!

Answer (score 4):

```
if (true)
```

always tests as true. You need to do

```
if (isEnglishConsonant(ch.charAt(0)))
```

instead.

Comment: @user233444: Happy to help. If there was an answer which solved your problem, remember to accept it. :)

Answer (score 4):

The 3rd line in code `isEnglishConsonant(ch.charAt(0));` seems to returning a boolean value which you are not storing in any variable. Please check with that if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void run() {
    String ch = readLine ("Enter an alphabet: ");        
    if (isEnglishConsonant(ch.charAt(0))){
        println("True");
    } else { 
        println("False");
    }
}

 private boolean isEnglishConsonant(char ch){
        switch (Character.toUpperCase(ch)){
            case 'A': case 'E': case 'I': case 'O': case 'U':
            return false;
        default:
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: but isEnglishConsonant(ch.charAt(0)) returns either true or false.

Comment: okey when it returns true it will execute println("True") and when it returns false it will execute println("False")

Answer (score 1):

Well if your checking if true is true, that will always be the case!

```
if (true){
```

Put the `isEnglishConsonant(ch.charAt(0))` instead of `true`, that's what you want to check after all!

Answer (score 1):

Here you are not comparing the boolean returning method directly. So, its not working. Change it to like

```
if(isEnglishConsonant(ch.charAt(0)))
{
println("True");
}
else
{
println("False");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (true)` will **always** return a `true`.

Rather do:

```
boolean consonant = isEnglishConsonant(ch.charAt(0));
if (consonant) {
        println("True");
} else {
        println("False");
}
```

You forgot to add a `break` on your `case` statement.

```
switch (Character.toUpperCase(ch)){
    case 'A': case 'E': case 'I': case 'O': case 'U':
            return false;
    break;

    default: 
        return true;
}
```

Comment: he is already returning false so why break ? break wont be reachable :)